# MFMailComposeViewController display a weird email popup with a colur

Tags: ios5, ios6

I'm using MFMailComposeViewController ([code snippet](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/)) to send an email from my iOS app. When I click the button in the view controller it popups the mail client with the background colour of my view controller as shown in below image. I have nothing especially added in to my view controller and though I change the colour of the view controller to white still the popup's colour is same. What is the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Please post *your* code so we can troubleshoot properly.

Comment: Same code in the http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/